# Calling login_required inside decorator

Tags: python, django, decorator

I'm trying to write a custom decorator, which will do some checks to see if a user has permission to access a page, but prior to that, the user needs to be authenticated. I thought of using Django's `login_required` decorator, and then doing my custom logic, however I can't seem to find any way to call the `login_required` decorator inside my own.

I do know that there are alternatives, like decorating my view like this:

```
@login_required
@my_custom_decorator
def my_view(request):
    pass
```

Or checking for `user.is_authenticated()` inside my decorator:

```
def my_custom_decorator(view_func):
    @wraps(view_func)
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            redirect(...)
```

However I'd like to user Django's logic from `login_required`.

Is there any way to call a decorator inside a decorator, or any other way to implement my logic without using 2 separate decorators?

Comment: Another option, if you use django restful framework, you can check the user's auth in a  APIView which inherite from GenericAPIView.

Comment: You might find [`user_passes_test`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your decorator returns a function, e.g.

```
def my_custom_decorator(view_func):
    @wraps(view_func)
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
    return wrapper
```

You can wrap that function in `login_required` before you return it:

```
def my_custom_decorator(view_func):
    @wraps(view_func)
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
    return login_required(wrapper)
```

Comment: Looks like I still have a lot to learn about decorators :) Thank you, worked like a charm!